# iPhone: Forcibly Update SBFakeTimeString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to create a program that displays the clock in hexadecimal (geektime.org format) in place of the current time.  I know that it is possible to set a custom string in that location in the com.apple.springboard.plist file under the SBFakeTimeString key, but it only updates when the status bar is refreshed (ie goto/from springboard).  Erica Sadun's MakeItMine app updates it instantly, but I am unable to find any source code.  I have found the dlsym/GSSendAppPreferencesChanged function (http://pastie.org/559006/wrap), but when executed, erases the .plist.  Is this even the correct way to go or should I use some sort of WinterBoard hack?

EDIT:
I know of the setBanner program from Erica Sadun, but everytime I run it it always outputs "Killed"

iPod Touch 1st Gen, 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to make a mobile substrate tweak. Dump Springboard's headers and find the part that updates the time in the status bar, hook that function and have it display your own time.